# Is it okay to difference data with different time intervals?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, time-series, difference-equations

I have a question that is from an old project and that I want to clarify purely for future research.

The question is, if you have a time-series that occurs at intermittent intervals, say once ever 4, 3 or 1 years, is it still okay to difference this data?

Here is the simple OLS:

d dependent variable = b0 + b1 d independent variable + e

This still appears to me to be a linear relationship, despite the change in the number of years between different obseravtions, these are still in line with the other variables and thus a change in one will still be linear to changes in the others.

For large changes in time for d dependent variable the changes in time the independent variable will also be large, and thus still relative and vice versa. Will this affect OLS in any way?

I would have used LN as well but this is just a example.

Comment: You have written $d$ dependent variables? Do you have many dependent variable (a VAR model)?

Comment: No I have not??

Comment: Okay. So what is d? In your equation there is d in LHS and RHS.

Comment: difference as in:   dependent variable v(t) - dependent variable v(t-n)